# sql query returns no result with many to many relation

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'd like to start with explaining what's my db looks like. I have the item table which is in relation many to many with two other tables tag and keyword.

```
table: item
columns: id, name, subcategory, category
```

```
table: item_tag_join
columns: itemId, tagId
```

```
table: tag
columns: id, name
```

```
table: item_keyword_join
columns: itemId, keywordId
```

```
table: keyword
columns: id, name
```

Now, what I want to do is I want to search through the keyword.name, tag.name, item.name, item.category and item.subcategory and return the item from item table, when any of the columns contain expected string.

With my query I manage to get the expected results as long as there're some records in the join tables. However when I have only one entry in my database, in the item table then the query returns empty.

i.e. I have added "Ferrari" to the item and I want to search "rar" it comes back with no results.
Im working with sqllite3 and here's the query I need Your help with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT item.* 
from item, tag, keyword 
LEFT JOIN item_tag_join ON 
item.id = item_tag_join.item_id
LEFT JOIN item_keyword_join ON item.id = item_keyword_join.item_id
WHERE UPPER(item.name) LIKE UPPER('%' || "cab"  || '%') 
or UPPER(item.category) LIKE UPPER('%' || "cab" || '%') 
or UPPER(item.sub_category) LIKE UPPER('%' || "cab" || '%') 
or (tag.id = item_tag_join.tag_id and UPPER(tag.name) LIKE UPPER('%' || "cab" || '%')) 
or (keyword.id = item_keyword_join.keyword_id and UPPER(keyword.name) LIKE UPPER('%' || "cab" || '%'));
```

Cheers.

Comment: Your query example is looking for items `LIKE` "cab" if this is a typo, please fix your example, otherwise you aren't going to get a result for "ferrari" since "cab" is not found inside that word.

Comment: At least this condition: `tag.id = item_tag_join.item_id` seems suspicious. It should be: `tag.id = item_tag_join.tag_id`, right?

Comment: @forpas ah sorry, my bad putting the example together. Edited my question, cheers.

Comment: Still the requirement is not clear. What does `Ferrari` and `rar` have to do with your query? Post sample data and expected results.

Comment: As you mentioned you are checking with only one record in database, please make sure that same item_id of item table should be there in other tables against which you are joining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it solved by breaking the statements into three separate selects and aplying UNION operator
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp